# Missing Time Series data in Hadoop

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce, time-series, interpolation

I have a big text file (in TBs), every line has a timestamp and some other data, like this:

```
timestamp1,data
timestamp2,data
timestamp5,data
timestamp7,data
...
timestampN,data
```

This file is ordered by timestamp but there might be gaps between consecutive timestamps. I need to fill those gaps and write the new file.

Can this be done in Hadoop Map Reduce? The reason for asking this question,to interpolate the missing lines I need the previous and next lines too. For Eg. To interpolate timestamp6, I need the values in timestamp5 and timestamp7. So what if, starting from timestamp7 sits in another data block in which case I will not be able to calculate timestamp6 at all..

Any other algorithm/solution? Maybe this can not be done with mapreduce? Can  we do this in RHADOOP?

(Pig/Hive solutions are also valid)

Answer (score 0):

Though my suggestion is a bit tedious and may impact a little bit performance also. You can implement your own RecordReader and at the end of all lines in the current split, get the first line of next split using its block location. I am suggesting this because, hadoop itself do this if last line of any mapper is incomplete. Hope this helps!!